# Laravel 5: Check for Specific Error

Tags: laravel-5

I have Password and Confirm Password inputs. I have coded these inputs so that in the event of an error the inputs highlight, like so:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'has-error' : '' }}>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control">
</div>
```

In my Controller, I validate these inputs as follows:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    ....
    'password'                 => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation'    => 'required',
    ....
]);
```

When either input is null and/or less than 8 characters, the inputs highlight as expected. However, when the inputs don't match, I would logically expect the Confirm Password input to highlight. However, it is the Password field that highlights, because that is the input that the "confirmed" rule is set to.

The "$errors->has()" method simply checks if an error exists for an input. Is there a way to check if an input has a *specific* kind of error?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the array of errors for a given input name by using:

```
{{ $errors->get('password') }}
```

So you can check if the password errors array has the confirmation error and then add the additional class to your confirmation input field:

```
 @if (in_array(trans('validation.confirmed', ['attribute' => 'password']), $errors->get('password'))) has-error @endif
```

And the helper methods may vary between Laravel versions:

**Laravel < 5.4**: `trans('validation.confirmed', ['attribute' => 'password'])`

**Laravel 5.4**: `__('validation.confirmed', ['attribute' => 'password'])`

Comment: To clarify, in Laravel 5.4 it would be "(in_array(__('validation.confirmed', ['attribute' => 'password']), $errors->get('password')))", correct? Using two underscores instead of "trans"?

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried it but you can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

Comment: Oh, interesting. So if I'm understanding it right I'm basically comparing the stored error message with the message I obtain from the invalid submission, correct?

Comment: That is correct, that part is optional ofcourse. Maybe I should'v left it out of the answer

Comment: What do you mean by optional?

Comment: You can just directly check it as: `in_array('The password confirmation does not match.', $errors->get('password'))` w/o retrieving it from the validation strings

Comment: A note for myself: To display a specific error: `{{ $errors->first('password') }}`